# How to put an HTML page inside a modal from a Wordpress Page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, modal-dialog

I'm trying to load an HTML page inside a Modal. I've got the following code on my wordpress page:

```
<a class='example7' href="http://google.com">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a>
```

But I'm not sure where I should paste the following JavaScript:

```
$(".example7").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a custom javascript file and [enqueue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) it from your `functions.php` file. Add the JavaScript code to that `custom.js` file.

Alternately, you could also add that within the `<script>` tags within your markup.